# What to do if OP doesn't accept answer and give any kind of feedback?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

So, I answered the 2 posts made by @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow and gave answers to all the questions he asked :

- [Riddle Time. I bet this is an easy one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71195/riddle-time-i-bet-this-is-an-easy-one/71196#71196)
- [Riddle Again, Riddle Again, What am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71202/riddle-again-riddle-again-what-am-i) (On Hold)

I believe that my answers are correct (as there are duplicates of his questions and they are easily found on the internet) and asked him to check on my answers, but for some reason, he only replies to other people's posts. He hasn't given me a reply until now and I really want my first checkmark :D

> What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do, I'm afraid. If a question-asker doesn't want to accept any answer, or just disappears from the site, no one can compel them to accept anything.

However, it's only been a day or so, and it's not at all unusual for people to be absent for a few days -- especially at weekends. So it's a bit early to be saying that the OP hasn't responded; he still might.

... Though, actually, *both* of those questions are now on hold, with some justification; each of them consists of multiple unrelated questions, which we discourage, and allegedly (I haven't checked but it seems plausible) most or all of those individual questions are duplicates of ones already on PSE. I suspect the questions will eventually get deleted, in whch case it doesn't really matter whether your answers were accepted :-).

Comment: Well, that goes my hope of ever getting an accepted answer :( Still, thanks for telling me this :D