# Should PSE establish a method to get intended answer to a question?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes (infrequently) I see that the OP not only does not accept an answer but does not provide his/her intended answer. There are a lot of questions with no accepted answers here.

This can be a bit frustrating to readers who are genuinely interested in OP's answer.

Is there a way PSE can ask/request or persuade the OP to either accept or post an answer?

Comment: I've tried to [fight this battle before](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6896/60644)... Novel solutions welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll go down the list of possible solutions I'm aware of. Some of these Code Golf is using, so I've linked them as examples.

- **Ping them in chat**: only works if the user is [pingable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321653/1017231) or a mod abuses [superpings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258040/1017231) (and they check their notifications).
- **Post a comment on the question**: only works if the user still checks their Stack Exchange notifications (either they still use SE in some fashion or they get email notifications of updates).
- **Post a comment on an answer**: only works if the user has posted a comment on said answer, otherwise they're not @-pingable.
- **Set up a [sidebar infobox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18028)**: only works if the user is on Puzzling SE to see it.
- **Customize our [first-time asker dialog](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23485)**: only works if the user bothers to read it initially.
- **Make a meta post**: only works if the user is active enough to see/remember meta. Also, Stiv already [tried that](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6896/69582).
- **Send a direct message, outside of chat**: [will never be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user).
- **Telepathically call to them across the vast Internet**: currently impossible.

Obviously, if you're using any of these possible solutions, please be polite and not overly pushy.